# export entire excel sheet to sql table with VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

having issue sending entire sheet to sql table. I have tried 2 different ways as shown below. both work in different ways. Ultimately I am struggling with exporting multiple rows of data to sql DB

this 1st way I can import multiple rows to sql table successfully with one click of the button, only problem is that the StartTime and FinishTime come to sql table as `00:00:00` even if I enter a normal time in excel

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim iRowNo As Integer
  Dim sEventDate, sID, sDeptCode, sOpCode, sStartTime, sFinishTime, sUnits  As String

  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    'Open a connection to SQL Server
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=db\db1;Initial Catalog=PTW;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    'Skip the header row
    iRowNo = 2
    'Loop until empty cell in FirstName
    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
    sEventDate = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
    sID = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
    sDeptCode = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
    sOpCode = .Cells(iRowNo, 4)
    sStartTime = .Cells(iRowNo, 5).Text
    sFinishTime = .Cells(iRowNo, 6).Text
    sUnits = .Cells(iRowNo, 7)
    'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
    conn.Execute "insert into dbo.TimeLog (EventDate, ID, DeptCode, Opcode, StartTime, FinishTime, Units) values ('" & sEventDate & "', '" & sID & "', '" & sDeptCode & "', '" & sOpCode & "', cast('" & dStartTime & "' as datetime), cast('" & dFinishTime & "' as datetime), '" & sUnits & "')"

    iRowNo = iRowNo + 1

    Loop

    MsgBox "Data Successfully Exported."
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
  End With
End Sub
```

this 2nd way works and sends the StartTime and FinishTime exactly as it is in excel table, but it only allows me to send one row to sql table at a time

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
  Dim strSQL As String

  strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.TimeLog" & _
     "(EventDate, ID, DeptCode, Opcode, StartTime, FinishTime, Units) " & _
     "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
  conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=db\db1;Initial Catalog=PTW;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

iRowNo = 1

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

  cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
  cmd.CommandText = strSQL



With Sheets("Sheet1")
  'Loop until empty cell in FirstName
   Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""

  cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("pEventDate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8, .Cells(iRowNo, 1))
  cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("pID", adInteger, adParamInput, , .Cells(iRowNo, 2))
  cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("pDeptCode", adVarChar, adParamInput, 2, .Cells(iRowNo, 3))
  cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("pOpCode", adVarChar, adParamInput, 2, .Cells(iRowNo, 4))
  cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("pStartTime", adDBTime, adParamInput, 0, .Cells(iRowNo, 5))
  cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("pFinishTime", adDBTime, adParamInput, 0, .Cells(iRowNo, 6))
  cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("pUnits", adInteger, adParamInput, , .Cells(iRowNo, 7))

  cmd.Execute


  iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
  Loop

  MsgBox "Data Successfully Exported"

End With

  conn.Close
  Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you must cast the value. In mssql, yourt time value is recognized as string.

cast('8:00:00' as datetime)

```
conn.Execute "insert into dbo.TimeLog (EventDate, ID, DeptCode, Opcode, StartTime, FinishTime, Units) values ('" & sEventDate & "', '" & sID & "', '" & sDeptCode & "', '" & sOpCode & "', cast('" & dStartTime & "' as datetime), cast('" & dFinishTime & "' as datetime), '" & sUnits & "')"
```

Comment: I am still sending the time to SQL table as `00:00:00` I even tried this and it still sends zeros `conn.Execute "insert into dbo.TimeLog (EventDate, ID, DeptCode, Opcode, StartTime, FinishTime, Units) values ('" & sEventDate & "', '" & sID & "', '" & sDeptCode & "', '" & sOpCode & "', cast('" & dStartTime & "' as time(0)), cast('" & dFinishTime & "' as time(0)), '" & sUnits & "')"`

Comment: Test  .Cells(iRowNo, 6).text

Comment: get an error when adding `Test.Cells(iRowNo, 6).Text` However, if I don't add the `Test` and only the `.Text` it is successful but i'm still sending `00:00:00`

Comment: also just updated the script that reflects all your suggestions thus far

Answer (score 0):

Adding this inside the loop of the first script was the result I was looking for...

```
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL
```